# Debug eclipse breakpoints disable for some classes

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

Currently I am debugging some code and I do not know the reason but for some classes it does not allow me to put breakpoints and I have the sources files...

Does anybody has ever had this problem?

When I try to put a breakpoint in any variable, it puts the breakpoint in the name of the class.
Here I share link with the image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=s4q3p2&s=8#.UzBHQ6ZGe3Q

Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you try? Do it actually put the breakpoints but the don't stop or the breakpoints didn't get marked on the code?

Comment: Perhaps the referenced code was compiled without the line-number attribute for the class files? In this case, try to recompile the corresponding classes yourself, if this is possible.

Comment: Hello Averroes, as I mentioned it does not allow me to put it in variables, but it is weird but when I click any variable, it puts the breakpoint in the class. Let me show a picture.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=s4q3p2&s=8#.UzBS0KZGe3Q

Comment: Is a jdk/jre bound in the Project's `Java Build Path`?